# Reading list from text file and converting it to string

Tags: python

**Hello, I recently started to learn Python, so that's my best explain to you, cause my English skills are not Perfectly.**
I made a script which is reading a list from text file, and then my problem is converting it to string, so I could display it in the print function. After doing that, when user is typing his "Nickname", lets say. The script is already readen the list from text file. Also the i don't know if used the split(',') Function, that should split the words with those , from the words in the text file used for list. Here are some pictures of my code.
https://gyazo.com/db797ca0998286248bf846ac70c94067 (Main code)
https://gyazo.com/918aaba9b749116d842fccb78f6204a8 (Text file - list of usernames which are "BANNED")
The text code file name is Listas_BAN.txt.

I've tried to do all this thing myself, i did some research before posting this, but many methods are outdated.

```
# Name
name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")
print("Welcome " + str(name))

def clear(): return os.system('cls')

clear()  # Clearina viska.

# define empty list
Ban_Listo_Read = open('Listas_BAN.txt', mode='r')
Ban_Listo_Read = Ban_Listo_Read.readlines()
Ban = Ban_Listo_Read.list(ban)
# Print the function (LIST) in string .
print("Your'e Banned. You'r nickname is - ", + Ban_Listo_Read).Select (' %s ', %s str(name)) # Select the User nickname from 
                                                                                                                                # The input which he typed. (Check for BAN, In the List.)
                                                                                                                                # Text file is the List Location . - Listas_BAN.txt
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR4Ff.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e0sb.png)

*I'm getting Wrong Syntax Error*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ll = open('untitled.txt', mode='r').readlines()
print("".join(ll).replace('\n', '.'))

name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")

if name in ll:
    print('your name {n} is in the list'.format(n=name))
```

EDIT:

plus, you shall consider using string formatting:

```
var1 = ...
var2 = ...
print("{x}...{y}".format(x=var1, y=var2)
```

or python 3.7

```
print(f"{var1}...{var2}")
```

EDIT:

```
f.readlines()
```

https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> If you want to read all the lines of a file in a list you can also use
>   list(f) or f.readlines().

Comment: Does the readlines picks only words after , or this function picks all the words, and shows them? Can i get more explanation?

Comment: And how to pick a username when user lets say writes his name in input(str(name) + " ,Hello we're checking if u are on our ban list" ), How to add a function which gets the name he inputed, and if it's in the list on the text file, then the script will no longer lets user to use the app. Lets say print("Sorry, but you're banned. You cannot use the app") sys.exit(1)

Comment: the replace('\n', '.')) how i understand, while reading the text file, makes a line below, and check other username, and at the function seens the end with . ?

Comment: it is just string formatting as when you read the text from file it includes linebreaks so you remove linebreaks with string formatting. you may want to avoid it depending on your needs. you do not have to replace it with comma also. it all depends on what you want exactly do.

Comment: Thanks for you support, and help :) Appreciate it.:) !

Comment: could you mark the answer as OK if you are happy with it unless you have more questions?

Comment: Just like to ask where do i need to use this print(f"{var1}...{var2}"), and f.readlines()  how i understand this code runs this function?

Comment: print(f"...) and f.readlines()   the first f is not the same as second f ... the second f can be anything e.g. a, b, xyz and it is just a name of the variable while the first f must be f .. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: https://gyazo.com/55e8e0ca307ebc6d22c6acb5be903da8 The function don't find the name in the text file, is the textfile lines correct? Lines - https://gyazo.com/2187717ff1af2513c8ab13f89e6dabf1

Comment: Hello? naivepredictor?

Comment: I am unable to open the link. Please paste some input samples in your question.